# Let $a$ be an element of a group $G$ and $|a| = 7.$ Show $a$ is the cube of some element of $G$.

Tags: group-theory

Having some trouble understanding how to proceed w/ this hw question:

> Let $a$ be an element of a group $G$ and $|a| = 7.$ Show $a$ is the cube of some element of $G$.

Attempt:

$a^7 = e$ by hypothesis.

So need to show $a = b^3$ for some $b \in G$

$a^7 = (b^3)^7 = b^{21} = e$

But is this even true? Have I actually shown something?

Comment: You have show that, since $b^{21}=e$, we have $\lvert b\rvert\mid 21$.

Comment: Thanks @Shaun for the edit

Comment: Not that If $a^7 = 3$ then $(a^5)^3 = a^{15}=a^7*a^7*a = a$.

Comment: 1) I think one thing that is confusing you is that $b^{21} = e$ does *not* mean that $|b|=21$ and that need not be true at all.  2) Note not only is there a $b$ so that $b^3=a$.  There are also $c,d,f,s$ so that $c^2=d^4=f^5=g^6 =a$.

Answer (score 5):

We have $$\begin{align}a^{15}&=a^{14}\cdot a \\ &=(a^7)^2\cdot a \\ &=e\cdot a \\ &=a,\end{align}$$ so that $a=b^3$ with $b=a^5\in G$.

Answer (score 4):

There *could* be a $b: |b| = 21; b^3 =a$ but you know *nothing* about the group and other elements.  In fact the group could be simply $G=<a>$ cyclic group.

So if this statement is *always* true it must be always true for $G = <a>$ and we have some $(a^k)^3 = a$.

Is that possible? is it always possible?

But if we have $(a^k)^3 = a^{3k} = a$ then we have $a = a^1= a^1*e^w = a^1*(a^7)^w = a^{7w+1}$.

If we can find a $k$ so that $3k = 7w+1$ for some $w$ we'd be done.... Because $(a^k)^3 = a^{3k} = a^{7w+1}=a*(a^7)^w = a$.

And as $3$ and $7$ are relatively prime we know we can find such a $k$.

Answer (score 3):

Is $a$ the cube of some power of $a$?  There are only six possible powers to check, so directly checking them is pretty quick...

Answer (score 3):

Let $b=a^{5}$, then $b^{3}=(a^{5})^{3}=a^{15}=(a^{7})^{2}a=ea=a$.

Comment: Why do you choose $b=a^5$ that's the part I'm kind of confused about.

Comment: Because $|a|=7$, So $a^{5}\neq e$ then i can select this element.

Comment: $a = a^7*a=a^8=a^8*a^7 = a^{15} = (a^5)^3$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider the subgroup $H$ of order $7$ generated by $a$ and consider the function $\varphi:H \to H$ defined by $\varphi(x)=x^3$.  Because $H$ is abelian, it's easy to show that $\varphi$ is in fact a homomorphism.  Show that $\ker \varphi = \{e \},$ which means that $\varphi$ is in fact an isomorphism, so (since $H$ is finite) it must be surjective.  And that, in turn, means that every element of $H$ must be the cube of some other element of $H$.

Comment: That's a lovely proof!

Answer (score 0):

This answer augments the other answers, since $3\times 5=15=2(7)+1$, by proving a slightly more general result.

> **Theorem:** Let $a\in G$ for some group $G$. If there exist $h, k\in\Bbb N$ such that $hk\equiv 1\pmod{\lvert a\rvert}$ (*i.e.*, there is some $\ell\in\Bbb Z$ with $hk=1+\ell\lvert a\rvert$), then $a$ has an $h$th root, $a^k$.

*Proof:* We have $1+\ell\lvert a\rvert=kh$ for some $\ell\in\Bbb Z$, so that $$\begin{align}a^{hk}&=a^{\ell\lvert a\rvert}\cdot a \\ &=(a^{\lvert a\rvert})^\ell\cdot a \\ &=e\cdot a \\ &=a,\end{align}$$ so that then $(a^k)^h=a$.$\square$

Answer (score 0):

Another (equivalent) way:

$$|a|=7\implies a^7=e\iff a\cdot a^6=e$$

Then multiplying both sides on the right by $(a^{-1})^6=a^{-6}$: $$a\cdot a^6\cdot a^{-6}=e\cdot a^{-6}=a^{-6}$$
So $$ae=a=a^{-6}=\left((a^{-1})^2\right)^3$$
where $b=(a^{-1})^2$ is an element of the group by existence of inverses and closure. Thus $a=b^3$.